# realloc() fails after repeated calls

Tags: c, malloc

I'm implementing some polynomial arithmetics in C. I use a dynamic struct to store integer factors and the polynomial degree.
Besides other functions I need the operation p[X]*X, so I try to implement some kind of right shift.

But after a few shifts realloc() crashes my program. In this example it's at the third call, but if I try to shift 2 and 4 times, it crashes after the second.

```
/* Simple polynom type with variable length and degree n-1. */
typedef struct {
    int n;
    int *factors;
} polynom_t;


polynom_t *poly_init(int n) {
    polynom_t *p_new = malloc(sizeof(polynom_t));
    p_new->n = n;
    p_new->factors = calloc(n, sizeof(int));

    return p_new;
}

void poly_clear(polynom_t *p) {
    free(p->factors);
    free(p);
    p = NULL;
}


void poly_set(polynom_t *p, int a[], int len){
    memcpy(p->factors, a, sizeof(int)*p->n);
}


void _poly_rsz(polynom_t *p, int n) {
    if (n != p->n) {
        p->n = n;

        // This realloc() seems to fail
        p->factors = realloc(p->factors, sizeof(int) * n);
    }
}


void _poly_lsr(polynom_t *p, int i) {
    _poly_rsz(p, p->n + i);
    memmove(p->factors + i, p->factors, sizeof(int)*(p->n));
    memset(p->factors, 0, sizeof(int)*i);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    polynom_t *p2 = poly_init(11);
    int a2[11] = {1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0};
    poly_set(p2, a2, 11);
    _poly_lsr(p2, 1);  // works as expected
    _poly_lsr(p2, 1);  // works as expected
    _poly_lsr(p2, 1);  // crash
    poly_clear(p2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Odd. when I run this code w/ gcc, I get this error: `*** error for object 0x6868cf0: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug`. However, when I step through the code, it works fine.

Comment: If on one of the supported platforms use Valgrind and it's probably be a lot clearer much sooner. But of course good old GDB alone also works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with this block of code here:

```
void _poly_lsr(polynom_t *p, int i) {
    _poly_rsz(p, p->n + i);
    memmove(p->factors + i, p->factors, sizeof(int)*(p->n));  // the problem is here!
    memset(p->factors, 0, sizeof(int)*i);
}
```

When you resize your polynomial, you reset it's count, which means, when you are adding 1, you are overflowing the bounds of your polynomial's array by 1. To fix, simply subtract `i` from the `memmove` count:

```
memmove(p->factors + i, p->factors, sizeof(int)*(p->n - i));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. After a five hour break watching movies with my friends, it seems so obvious and I feel a little bit embarrassed.